# I failed installing Ubuntu for dual booting with my window 10

Tags: dual-boot

I'm sorry for a stupid question but I'm kinda in panic and don't know what to do.

I tried to install Ubuntu on my window 10 as dual booting following a tutorial video but failed because of this error:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766945

My laptop is still on Ubuntu but I can't do anything and power off my laptop and I don't know what to do!!! Should I just press shut down button, restart my laptop and reboot in Windows??? What should I do? Can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: you can always just press power to restart. Are you stuck in the live version or the one you installed?

Comment: @Esther Ubuntu is the one that I installed. Then would window 20 be my live version ? Do I just restart and press F12 to see the menu and choose window ??

Comment: You're very confused and need to understand some crucial details before making mistakes. (1) The bug in question is likely NOT applicable. Any preinstalled Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode since at least 2012. (2) When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature *before+ running the Ubuntu installer is a MUST. Disabling Fast Boot (UEFI) is always useful and disabling Secure Boot (UEFI) is optional but recommended.